# Missing Azure AD B2C b2c-extensions-app

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Originally I deleted an Azure AD B2C directory, which according to the MSDN guide included removing the b2c-extensions-app. When I thereafter created a new Azure AD B2C directory with the same name, the b2c-extensions-app was not created automatically.

Following this, I tried to create a new Azure AD B2C directory with a different name, which also missed the b2c-extensions-app.

How come both of them misses the b2c-extensions-app? 
And what can be done to fix this?

**EDIT:**
To answer the second question. When creating an Azure AD B2C directory the b2c-extensions-app might not be created right away. In my case it appeared after a while, which can be good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app was deleted less than 30 days ago, you can restore it using Azure AD Graph's [/deletedApplications/{application_id}/restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/functions-and-actions#restore) api.

If the application was deleted longer than that, there is no way to restore it, which, in the case of b2c-extensions-app, means that **you need to create a new Azure AD B2C directory with a new name**. If you create a new directory but do so with the same name, the b2c-extensions-app will not be re-created in that new directory.

Comment: But does the newly created b2c AD have the same application id as the old one, e.g. is it possible in my scenario to restore the b2c-extensions-app of the old b2c AD to add it to the new one with the same name? @Saca

Comment: No, the newly created Azure AD B2C won't have the same application ID nor is it possible to make it so.

Comment: So there is no way to ever reuse the name of a removed Azure AD B2C since the b2c-extensions-app won't be created, either automatically  or manually, in this case?

Comment: If you're referring to the tenant name (x.onmicrosoft.com), correct, can't be reused at this time. I'd recommend requesting this feature in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv